# delete records from multiple objects via apex batch class

Tags: batch, delete

I have a requirement for a process that would delete qualified records from multiple objects. There are about 5 objects and criteria for deletion is the same for all objects. I want to do all of it in one batch class, possibly by iterating through each object, adding records for deletion to one common list and then perfom a delete. Is this possible? Can someone please help with the syntax?

Thank you!

Comment: Will you already know the ID's of the records you want to delete?

Comment: I wouldn't know the id of the records i'd need to delete. I have to query for those records first.

Comment: @user9862. If you liked the idea, it would be useful for other developers if you mark it as the solution ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I decided to implement my requirement. Still need to test it, but high level seems to be working:

```
global class DeleteRecords implements Database.Batchable<string>, Database.Stateful  {
global boolean bReRun = false; //will be used to determine if batch has to re-run in case there are more that 10K of records
global Iterable<string> start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
    return new list<String> { 'object1', 'object2', 'object3','object4','object5'}; //list of strings with my object names
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, list<string> lstsObjectName) {
    list<sObject> lstDeleteRecords = new list<sObject>();
    for(string strObjectName : lstsObjectName) {
        for(sObject objsObject : database.query('Select Id from ' + strObjectName + ' where for_delete__c = TRUE')) {
            if(lstDeleteRecords.size() < 9998)
                lstDeleteRecords.add(objsObject);
            else {
                bReRun = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    lstDeleteRecords.sort();
    delete lstDeleteRecords;
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
    if(bReRun) {
         Database.executebatch(new DeleteRecords());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

You can combine up to 10 types of `SObject` in one list for `DML` **as long as they are grouped by type**. See [this post](http://jessealtman.com/2013/08/conserve-dml-statements/) by Jesse Altman for more color on that.

You can accomplish what you are looking for by using an `Iterable`. Take a look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm) for a good example of how to use an `Iterable` in a batch (at the bottom). You will want to iterate over a `List<SObject>`. In your constructor, add your various queries one by one to this list.

Rough example:

```
global class CustomIterable implements Iterator<SObject>
{
    final List<SObject> records;
    global CustomIterable()
    {
        records = new List<SObject>();
        records.addAll((List<SObject>)[SELECT Id FROM Account]); // WHERE...
        records.addAll((List<SObject>)[SELECT Id FROM Contact]); // WHERE...
        records.addAll(Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Opportunity')); // WHERE...
    }

    // rest of implementation
}
```

This general approach should get you started.

Comment: Adrian, thank you for your response! Is there a limit to the amount of records returned when using the iterator?

Comment: Not that I know of, at least within a single iteration. Your total record count will be subject to `LimitQueryRows`, which is 50,000.

Comment: Adrian, I tried this but getting "Incompatible argument type List<Account> for All method on List<SObject>

Comment: @pmvsdt I updated with a couple different ways to get around that. You can cast the list if you want to use standard queries, or use `Database.query`, which returns a generic `List<SObject>` already.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to call batches in chain, so you can get advantage of Database.queryLocator that is able to return more records than Iterator.

On each chain you can query the object you want to remove and delete it. You would be able to set different scopeSize for each one as well if this is required. Maybe objectA is more complex than objectB

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful
{
    private Integer currentChain;

    private Integer scopeSize;

    public MyBatch()
    {
        currentChain = 1;
    }

    public MyBatch(Integer chain)
    {
        currentChain = chain;
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String qry;

        if(currentChain == 1)
        {
            qry = 'Select Id From ObjectA__c';
        }
        else(currentChain == 2)
        {
            qry = 'Select Id From ObjectB__c';
        }

        return Database.getQueryLocator(qry);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
    {
        delete scope;       
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        if(currentChain == 1)
        {
            MyBatch mb = new MyBatch(currentChain++);
            Database.execute(mb, scopeSize);
        }
        else(currentChain == 2)
        {
            sendEmail();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably wrap that `DML` in some sort of `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Agustina, thank you for your response. The concept is simple to understand and i think this is the route I'll be trying to implement for my requirement.

Comment: Also you should really use a list or map to track which chain you're in instead of those `if`/`else` chains. With 10 separate objects that would get really ugly.

Comment: Agree with that, will do!

Comment: Of course!! @user9862 I didn't include any error handler or way to recovery from an issue with rollback, or sendEmails. Just left the code as simpler as possible, so developer can include all their fantastic ideas. Batch is not so simple every ;)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your start with the following:

```
global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        // Database.getQueryLocator([Select Name  from blah LIMIT 10000]);
        List<sObject> lstUPQs = [select Id from Account where ... LIMIT 5000];
        List<sObject> lstJRs = [select Id from Contact where ... LIMIT 5000];
        
        List<sObject> lstAll = new List<sObject>();
        lstAll.addAll(lstUPQs);
        lstAll.addAll(lstJRs);
        
        return lstAll;
    }

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
       
        delete scope;
    }
```