# can start method of batch apex return list of primitive datatypes

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

can start method of batch apex return list of primitive datatypes.

I am supposed to get data for all sObjects and add them to respective lists and delete respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81284/delete-records-from-multiple-objects-via-apex-batch-class) post, which "Delete records from multiple objects via apex batch class"